# How to specialize template for array of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I try to make an example to pass an array of strings to a specialized template constructor, but actually I didn't got any error, but this example it's not working.
I tried like this:
call the template class constructor:

```
int ia[] = { 6, 7, 8, 3 };
const sav<int> si( ia, sizeof( ia ) / sizeof( ia[ 0 ] ) );
std::string sa[] = { "World" , "Hello" };
const sav<std::string> ss( sa, sizeof( sa ) / sizeof( sa[ 0 ] ) );
```

And in my template I have:

```
template<typename T>
class sav{
public:
  sav(T* givenArray,size_t size) {
     std::cout<<"not specialized" << std::endl;
  }
};

/* ** */
template<>
class sav<std::string[]>{
public:
    sav(std::string* givenArray[],size_t size) {     
       std::cout<<"specialized" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And I want to use the second one in `ss` case, but this still works with the first one.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I can't understand what you are trying to achieve, what is the problem, if there is any error (then post the error)? Have a look on these rules on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @kosnik I don't get any error. I want to use the second template if the parameter in  `givenArray` is an array of strings, but this code use the first, and I don't know why, and how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying the template argument as `std::string`, but not an array. I suppose you should specialize the template as

```
template<>
class sav<std::string>{
public:
    sav(std::string* givenArray,size_t size) {     
       std::cout<<"specialized" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uDXSUia8VxSdyQSf)

Comment: in this case I got `error: no matching function for call to 'sorted_array_view<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::sorted_array_view(std::__cxx11::string [2], unsigned int)'`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you use `sav<std::string>`, when the specialization is `sav<std::string[]>`.

The specialization should be `sav<std::string>`.

Of and your specialized `sav` constructor is wrong as well, as the first argument is an "array" of pointers to `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

If understood your intention correct the specialized constructor should be declared like this:

```
template<>
class sav<std::string[]> {
public:
    sav(std::string givenArray[], size_t size) {
        std::cout << "specialized" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and used like this:

```
const sav<std::string[]> ss(sa, sizeof(sa) / sizeof(sa[0]));
```

Update:

You can also declare the constructor like this:

```
template<>
class sav<std::string> {
public:
    sav(std::string* givenArray , size_t size) {
        std::cout << "specialized" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and then call it the following way if you want to avoid the array declaration :

```
const sav<std::string> ss(sa, sizeof(sa) / sizeof(sa[0]));
```

Comment: Yes, this is working fine, thank you, but  why I have to use like `sav<std::string[]>`, in first case, with `sav<int> si` the template understand there is an array, in this case why didn't?

Comment: You could also declare the constructor as pointer to string. Arrays can be handled similar as pointers.